# Model.new is returning a Mongoid::Criteria instead of a Model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Part of my app directory setup looks like:

```
app
  models
    tasks
      email_task.rb
      signup_task.rb
      task.rb
```

task.rb contains:

```
class Task
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  VALID_STATUSES = %w{ new pending complete }

  field :status, type: String, default: 'new'

  # Scopes
  VALID_STATUSES.each do |status|
    scope status.to_sym, -> { where(status: status) }

    define_method "#{status}?" do
      self.status == status
    end
  end
end
```

signup_task.rb contains:

```
class SignupTask < Task
end
```

In the rails console, when I do `SignupTask.new`, I expect it to return an instance of the SignupTask model. Maybe something like this:

```
irb(main):027:0> SignupTask.new
=> #<SignupTask _id: 557552b74372615e3b010000, created_at: .....>
```

But instead, it returns a Mongoid::Criteria:

```
irb(main):027:0> SignupTask.new
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"status"=>"new"}
  options:  {}
  class:    SignupTask
  embedded: false>
```

I notice that commenting out the `# Scopes` section fixes the issue, but why does that change the behavior in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` is part of your statuses.

You create the `new` scope within your metaprogramming loop.

```
scope status.to_sym, -> { where(status: status) }

# => scope :new, -> { where(status: 'new') }
```

I guess you ignored the warning saying you overwrite an existing method, and there you end up :)

Choose another status name or scope name.